# Make Jscript less likely to be copied from site?

Tags: html, jscript

The issue is I have a bit of jscript which once the user enters text in text area it changes the text and puts in into another text area.

What I want to happen is that if someone copy's this then when the person who copied it has a message appear in the text area saying please ask for my permission.

Here is a example of someone who I found got this to work but not sure how they did it?

```
function flip(){var _0x4f33=["\x68\x72\x65\x66","\x66\x73\x79\x6D\x62\x6F\x6C\x73\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F","\x73\x65\x61\x72\x63\x68","\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2D\x73\x79\x6D\x62\x6F\x6C\x73\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F","\x66\x69\x6C\x65\x3A\x2F\x2F","\x48\x69\x21\x20\x3D\x29\x20\x50\x6C\x65\x61\x73\x65\x2C\x20\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x61\x63\x74\x20\x6D\x65\x20\x61\x74\x20\x69\x68\x6F\x72\x2E\x69\x62\x6D\x40\x67\x6D\x61\x69\x6C\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x20\x69\x66\x20\x79\x6F\x75\x20\x77\x61\x6E\x74\x20\x74\x6F\x20\x75\x73\x65\x20\x61\x62\x6F\x71\x65\x20\x6F\x6E\x20\x79\x6F\x75\x72\x20\x77\x65\x62\x73\x69\x74\x65\x2E\x20\x49\x2C\x20\x61\x74\x20\x6C\x65\x61\x73\x74\x2C\x20\x77\x61\x6E\x74\x20\x74\x6F\x20\x62\x65\x20\x73\x75\x72\x65\x2C\x20\x79\x6F\x75\x27\x6C\x6C\x20\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x20\x74\x6F\x20\x6D\x79\x20\x46\x53\x79\x6D\x62\x6F\x6C\x73\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x20\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x20\x74\x68\x65\x20\x70\x61\x67\x65\x20\x6F\x6E\x20\x77\x68\x69\x63\x68\x20\x79\x6F\x75\x20\x75\x73\x65\x20\x69\x74\x2E","\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65","\x6F\x72\x69\x67\x69\x6E\x61\x6C","\x66","\x66\x6C\x69\x70\x70\x65\x64"];var result,hr=location[_0x4f33[0]];if(hr[_0x4f33[2]](_0x4f33[1])==-1&&hr[_0x4f33[2]](_0x4f33[3])==-1&&hr[_0x4f33[2]](_0x4f33[4])==-1){result=_0x4f33[5];}else{var result=flipString(document[_0x4f33[8]][_0x4f33[7]][_0x4f33[6]]);};document[_0x4f33[8]][_0x4f33[9]][_0x4f33[6]]=result;}function flipString(aString){var _0xf177=["\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68","\x68\x72\x65\x66","\x63\x68\x61\x72\x41\x74","\x74\x6F\x4C\x6F\x77\x65\x72\x43\x61\x73\x65","","\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E","\x66\x69\x6C\x65\x3A\x2F\x2F","\x73\x65\x61\x72\x63\x68","",""];var last=aString[_0xf177[0]]-1;var hr=location[_0xf177[1]];var result=new Array(aString[_0xf177[0]]);for(var i=last;i>=0;--i){var c=aString[_0xf177[2]](i);var r=flipTable[c];r=r?r:flipTable[c[_0xf177[3]]()];result[last-i]=r?r:c;};var res=result[_0xf177[5]](_0xf177[4]);if(hr[_0xf177[7]](_0xf177[6])!==-1){res+=_0xf177[8]+_0xf177[9];};return res;}var flipTable={'?':'\u00BF','!':'\u00A1',a:'\u0250',b:'q',c:'\u0254',d:'p',e:'\u01DD',f:'\u025F',g:'\u0183',h:'\u0265',i:'\u0131',j:'\u027E',k:'\u029E',m:'\u026F',n:'u',r:'\u1d1a',t:'\u0287',v:'\u028C',w:'\u028D',y:'\u028E',A:'\u2200',E:'\u018e',F:'\u2132',H:'H',N:'N',I:'I',O:'O',W:'M',Z:'Z',S:'S',X:'X',T:'\u22a5',V:'\u039B',C:'\u03FD',P:'\u0500',R:'\u1588',U:'\u2229','.':'\u02D9','[':']','(':')','{':'}',"\'":',','<':'>','"':'\u201e','_':'\u203E','2':'5','3':'\u0190','4':'\u152d','6':'9','7':'\u2c62','\u203F':'\u2040','\u2045':'\u2046','\u2234':'\u2235','\r':'\n'};var _0xc5da=[];for(i in flipTable){flipTable[flipTable[i]]=i;};
```

If anyone has any idea of how I could do this, it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is no 100% complete way of stopping the user from copying your source code. No matter what you do, a determined user can still get the code.**
That said, these 2 websites may help you: http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com and http://htmlobfuscator.com/. Just remember, though, that this can still be bypassed. There are other online tools that can "de-obfuscate" Javascript. And there is no way to find out when the user is copying your code, so you can't make them ask for permission.

Comment: I think his example does not obfuscate JavaScript, but rather the content of the page.

Answer (score 1):

They probably encrypted the text on the page and decrypted it in JavaScript.

Comment: I do not think this works. It just bothers your users.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the no absolute cure.

There used to be a commercial program called "HTML Armor" that did all the things that you asked, to include making the finished pages not display from the user's own saved ("stolen") copy of your webpage.

Unfortunately, if it can be encrypted by on human, it can just as easily be broken by another!

Another drawback, many anti-virus software products will flag most of those scripts as malicious as soon as they are copied to the user's temporary internet files folder. After all, that IS what they are designed to do. This is because so many malicious coders have written worms and other "bad-ware", and usually used some form of encryption in their scripts. There are really only so many ways to encrypt a script to where it can be decrypted when it is needed!

So I really do not have any other answers for you.